# Why isn't my bootstrap css applying in Django

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrapping

I am currently learning django and I tried to apply bootstrap css for my little project but it keeps throwing this following error and doesn't apply.

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/%20%20%20%20bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('application/xml') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

This is my code.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/
    bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="
    sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>crm1</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'accounts/navbar.html'%}

    {% block content %}
    


    {% endblock %}

    <hr>
    <h5>Our footer</h5>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your template doesn't seem to have `{% load static %}` at the top. [Read docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a new directory (with a static name) in your Django project. And re-create a new directory (named css).

```
Directory tree :
Your Project -> new directory -> static -> new directory -> css
And download bootstrap.min.css file and copy/paste into css file.

project
|_static
        |_css
             |_bootstrap.min.css
```

You can change your code as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}"/>
</head>
<body>

   {% block body %}


    {% endblock %}


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it helped me alot i hope i could help someone else like me i  the future